# What is the difference between a stored procedure and a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, view

I am confused about a few points:

1. What is the difference between a stored procedure and a view?
2. When should I use stored procedures, and when should I use views, in SQL Server?
3. Do views allow the creation of dynamic queries where we can pass parameters?
4. Which one is the fastest, and on what basis is one faster than the other?
5. Do views or stored procedures allocate memory permanently?
6. What does it mean if someone says that views create a virtual table, while procedures create a materials table?

Please let me know about more points, if there are any.

Comment: I would ask when should I use a view instead of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

A view represents a **virtual** table.  You can join multiple tables in a view and use the view to present the data as if the data were coming from a single table.

A stored procedure uses parameters to do a function... whether it is updating and inserting data, or returning single values or data sets.

[Creating Views and Stored Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365311.aspx) - has some information from Microsoft as to when and why to use each.

Say I have two tables:

- `tbl_user`, with columns: `user_id`, `user_name`, `user_pw`
- `tbl_profile`, with columns: `profile_id`, `user_id`, `profile_description`

So, if I find myself querying from those tables A LOT... instead of doing the join in EVERY piece of SQL, I would define a view like:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_user_profile
AS
  SELECT A.user_id, B.profile_description
  FROM tbl_user A LEFT JOIN tbl_profile B ON A.user_id = b.user_id
GO
```

Thus, if I want to query `profile_description` by `user_id` in the future, all I have to do is:

```
SELECT profile_description FROM vw_user_profile WHERE user_id = @ID
```

That code could be used in a stored procedure like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getDesc
    @ID int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT profile_description FROM vw_user_profile WHERE user_id = @ID
END
GO
```

So, later on, I can call:

```
dbo.getDesc 25
```

and I will get the description for `user_id` 25, where the `25` is your parameter.

There is obviously a lot more detail, this is just the basic idea.

Comment: But i can join can join multiple tables in stored procedure as well where i don't have to give parameter.

Comment: but WHY would you do that? what are you trying to accomplish?  You can use a view AS a table... stored procedures are for DOING things... views are for making your life easier.

Comment: Think of a view as a stored query so if you have two tables that you find you have to join a lot to get work done, you can create a view to work against so you don't have to join them all of the time.

Comment: if i need to return a data set from the server based on parameters... use a stored procedure called from your server side code. there are two different animals.

Comment: OK , if create  a view then from view only i can get the data, but after all it have to refer the actual tables to get the data then where the difference lie in stored procedure and views

Comment: But after all in View i also have to put join to get data from the multiple tables.

Comment: right but it STORES your view then... so that you can call it like a single table.  that way you creat your join once, and any future uses reference the view directly which calls the underlying sql as if it WAS a table.

Comment: Still thinking that when the same task can be done by SP too, like if i create a sp and any body knowing about that sp can access the data.

Answer (score 166):

Plenty of info available [here](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/450173-views-vs-stored-procedures-whats-difference)

Here is a good summary:

**A Stored Procedure:**

- Accepts parameters
- Can **NOT** be used as building block in a larger query
- Can contain several statements, loops, IF ELSE, etc.
- Can perform modifications to one or several tables
- Can NOT be used as the target of an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE 
  statement.

**A View:**

- Does **NOT** accept parameters
- Can be used as building block in a larger query
- Can contain only one single SELECT query
- Can **NOT** perform modifications to any table
- But can (sometimes) be used as the target of an INSERT, UPDATE or 
  DELETE statement.

Comment: Also Views shouldn't contain any "order by" or "top" clauses

Comment: What does mean by "can NOT be used as the target of an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement"? Can't we use INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE in Stored Procedure ?

Comment: "A view, does NOT accept parameters", it's not true? The video for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK-mWjUxKpw

Comment: Views can perform modifications to base table/tables:
https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/09/updateable-views-part-40.html

Comment: @ArsmanAhmad to clarify: You CAN use INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE in a Stored Procedure. But the Stored Procedure can NOT be the target of INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements. For example: you cannot insert data into a Stored Procedure. A Stored Procedure is not a table of any kind, so you cannot INSERT data into it, UPDATE data in it or DELETE data in it.

Answer (score 16):

A SQL View is a virtual table, which is based on SQL SELECT query. A view references one or more existing database tables or other views. It is the snap shot of the database whereas a stored procedure is a group of Transact-SQL statements compiled into a single execution plan.

View is simple showcasing data stored in the database tables whereas a stored procedure is a group of statements that can be executed.

A view is faster as it displays data from the tables referenced whereas a store procedure executes sql statements.

Check this article : [View vs Stored Procedures](http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/answer/Views-vs-Stored-procedures) . Exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Mentioned link "View vs Stored Procedures" refers to a page ONLY about stored procedures, no word about Views!

Answer (score 12):

First you need to understand, that both are different things. `Stored Procedures` are best used for `INSERT-UPDATE-DELETE` statements. Whereas `Views` are used for `SELECT` statements. You should use both of them.

<strike>In views you cannot alter the data.</strike> Some databases have updatable Views where you can use `INSERT-UPDATE-DELETE` on `Views`.

Comment: You can alter data in underlying table using Views. Views are updateable.

Comment: The views are updatable, but with certain conditions: you can update/insert data in one of the base tables which are in the from clause of the view.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the above comments, I would like to add few points about Views.

1. Views can be used to hide complexity. Imagine a scenario where 5 people are working on a project but only one of them is too good with database stuff like complex joins. In such scenario, he can create Views which can be easily queried by other team members as they are querying any single table.
2. Security can be easily implemented by Views. Suppose we a Table **Employee** which contains sensitive columns like **Salary**, **SSN number**. These columns are not supposed to be visible to the users who are not authorized to view them. In such case, we can create a View selecting the columns in a table which doesn't require any authorization like *Name*, *Age* etc, without exposing sensitive columns (like Salary etc. we mentioned before). Now we can remove permission to directly query the table **Employee** and just keep the read permission on the View. In this way, we can implement security using Views.

Answer (score 8):

A view is a simple way to save a complex `SELECT` in the database.

A store procedure is used when simple SQL just isn't enough. Store procedures contain variables, loops and calls to other stored procedures. It's a programming language, not a query language.

1. Views are static. Think of them as new tables with a certain layout and the data in them is created on the fly using the query you created it with. As with any SQL table, you can sort and filter it with `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.
2. The depends on what you do.
3. The depends on the database. Simple views just run the query and filter the result. But databases like Oracle allow to create a "materialized" view which is basically a table which is updated automatically when the underlying data of the view changes.

   A materialized view allows you to create indexes on the columns of the view (especially on the computed columns which don't exist anywhere in the database).
4. I don't understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 6):

Mahesh is not quite correct when he suggests that you can't alter the data in a view. So with patrick's view

```
CREATE View vw_user_profile AS 
Select A.user_id, B.profile_description
FROM tbl_user A left join tbl_profile B on A.user_id = b.user_id
```

I CAN update the data ... as an example I can do either of these ...

```
Update vw_user_profile Set profile_description='Manager' where user_id=4
```

or

```
Update tbl_profile Set profile_description='Manager' where user_id=4
```

You can't INSERT to this view as not all of the fields in all of the table are present and I'm assuming that PROFILE_ID is the primary key and can't be NULL.
However you can sometimes INSERT into a view ...

I created a view on an existing table using ...

```
Create View Junk as SELECT * from [TableName]
```

THEN

```
Insert into junk (Code,name) values 
('glyn','Glyn Roberts'),
('Mary','Maryann Roberts')
```

and

```
DELETE from Junk Where ID>4
```

Both the INSERT and the DELETE worked in this case

Obviously you can't update any fields which are aggregated or calculated but any view which is just a straight view should be updateable.

If the view contains more than one table then you can't insert or delete but if the view is a subset of one table only then you usually can.

Answer (score 3):

1. A VIEW is a dynamic query where you can use a "WHERE"-Clause
2. A stored procedure is a fixed data selection, which returns a predefined result
3. Nor a view, nor a stored procedure allocate memory. Only a materialized view
4. A TABLE is just one ENTITY, a view can collect data from different ENTITIES or TABLES

Comment: This is not correct.  A View is a stored SELECT statement and cannot accept parameters. A stored procedure is dynamic and can accept parameters.  You can use WHERE clauses in both and you can query data from multiple tables in both.

Comment: 1 - Only if you are executing the source code of the view and alter the value for your `WHERE` clause. Otherwise, if you save your `view` definition with a specific value in the `WHERE` clause, every time you call it will return the dataset for that value. Always.

Answer (score 3):

Main difference is that when you are querying a view then it's definition is pasted into your query. Procedure could also give results of query, but it is compiled and for so faster. Another option are indexed views..

Answer (score 2):

@Patrick is correct with what he said, but to answer your other questions a View will create itself in Memory, and depending on the type of Joins, Data and if there is any aggregation done, it could be a quite memory hungry View.

Stored procedures do all their processing either using Temp Hash Table e.g #tmpTable1 or in memory using @tmpTable1. Depending on what you want to tell it to do.

A Stored Procedure is like a Function, but is called Directly by its name. instead of Functions which are actually used inside a query itself.

Obviously most of the time Memory tables are faster, if you are not retrieveing alot of data.