# MySQL: Tables vs Views vs Routines

Tags: mysql, postgresql, view, mysql-routines

What is the difference Between MySQL : Tables vs Views vs Routines(Store Procedures)?

I am familiar with tables. heard about views and routines . for both name itself says , it can allow to view data's is it?

In MySQL I am having these 3 under schemas... Does these 3 are available in other SQL too like POSTGRES?

What is the functional difference between these 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a stored procedure and a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194995/what-is-the-difference-between-a-stored-procedure-and-a-view)

Comment: i am asking about mysql schema having tables views procedures. that question have only views and procedures alone even for sql-server. kindly check the difference . is there anything wrong tell me

Comment: A schema (database in MySQL) is just a name space to organize database objcts. It doesn't make much sense to keep one type of object in one schema. They are more useful for grouping objects that belong together.

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell.

A table has physical storage of data.

A view is an sql query that can be queried like a table but does not have any physical storage as such.

A procedure is a programmable sub-routine that can perform any number of actions permissible to the database base and the executing user.

These definitions can vary depending on the db solution that you are using. I suggest reading the relevant documentation.